# yii table sorter customize ajaxurl

Tags: php, ajax, yii, tablesorter

I have my code:

```
ajaxUrl : '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("abc/def");?>&page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol} ',
```

source :

```
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html
```

and it did work, but then in yii manager url
we clean the url format so, we remove index.php in url,
so it didn't accept unnual $_GET anymore.

My current code is:

```
            ajaxUrl : '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("abc/def",array("page"=>"{page}"));?>',
```

but it didn't return the unnual page(just sample so I just use one parameter. Another try is:

```
            ajaxUrl : Yii.app.createUrl('abc/def',{page:page,size:size,sortList:col,filterList:fcol}),
```

and the result is nothing, I was trying using yii with javascript but another fail. I think the problem is the value when in value is set to be javascript, but when I'm input in array createurl it was just string.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sory if it's too technically,,

it's solved with change & to ?

code :

```
ajaxUrl : '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("Dasboard/DataAds");?>?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}&{filterList:fcol} ',//{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}',
```